# How to instruct NAnt to include the console output to its log file defined in '-l' option?

Tags: build, nant

I have a custom NAnt task, which writes to console like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Status message: " + message);
```

If I run my buildscript specifying the log to write to (`-l:log.txt`), the log file doesn't contain those lines which come from Console.WriteLine. The console window displays all info, obviously.

I know I can redirect the output to log in this way instead:

```
nant ... > log.txt
```

But this is not what I'm looking for.

So, the questions are:

- Is it possible to instruct NAnt somehow to grab this console output to its log?
- Should I change the custom task to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task should use NAnt Logger instead of writing to console. Plain and simple. Redirection won't work when NAnt is using other loggers, e.g. XML output.

Comment: Right, it was simple. Thanks!

Comment: There is no code in answer. You are able to use project.Log(Level.Info, "test"); to write something to log.